# EWS-JAVA-API Self signed certificate for Exchange Server 2010

Tags: exchange-server, client-certificates, ewsjavaapi

i´am using ews-java-api and i need to use self-signed certificate to communicate with exchange-server, which is in same network like me.

1. Which name for self-signed certificate i should use to match with
   exchange server 2010 entry ? it is domainname?
2. How can i use created certificate by my java-code, where i try to
   autodiscovering the endpoint of exchange-server2010?

I´ve only created one certificate by keytool, but no idea how can i use it.
And i guess, that i have to create certificate with the correct name-entry, which is known by the exchange-server2010